# jQuery not working on Windows Server 2008, IIS 7

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am deploying an ASP.NET MVC to Windows Server 2008. I have installed ASP.NET MVC 1, but jQuery is not working on any of the pages. Anyone had this problem?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I'm having the same problem... specifically on Windows Server 2008/IIS 7 and the jQuery Datepicker. Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect a problem with the path being used to load the scripts.  Is your web site at the root or in a subdirectory on the server?  See this question and see if the answers there don't help.

[jQuery library location wants to be referenced differently on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730336/jquery-library-location-wants-to-be-referenced-differently-on-server)

Comment: This does not seem to be the problem

Comment: All my scripts are accessible(can download them) from the page's source view and some of the code in my script file is working fine by ajax call aren't, any clue?