# Jquery Datepicker Works in visual Studio but not when deployed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, razor

I've developed a page where I have a few dates to put in to an input box. 
However when I do this with Datepicker it only works in visual studio 2010.
When we have deployed to IIS 7 it just says

> Message: Object does not support this property or method

when loading the page.

Below is a code sample for what I'm trying to do. I don't mind having a button to activate the datepicker but as it is now it just doesn't work when in deployment. Does anyone knows anything that could help me here?

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RunDate, "Kørselsdato")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RunDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RunDate, "Vælg venligst en dato")
    </div>



    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Opret" />
    </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#RunDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
</script>
```

Edit:
I'm using this in the Layout File. so those suggesting to use@URL.Content can see that I am already doing so. or if this is not what you mean could you explain more closely what you mean ?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">
```

Comment: when you deploy, Get the Firebug installed on your machine and open the site in the Firefox, and see the events happening, when you try to pick the date from the datepicker.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730336/jquery-library-location-wants-to-be-referenced-differently-on-server . it might help you

Comment: @Helbo if you have chrome installed, you can see on inspect element that will tell you if any part of jQuery is failed.

Comment: I'm not allowed to install Firefox or chrome on this development PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your javascript is not deployed properly. Or your path to javascript files is not proper.

Use `Url.Content` to confirm accurate relative path where you have referenced the javascripts.

Like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.src.js")"></script>
```

Comment: you were correct some of the scripts did not transfer with the site to the deployed location.